# NSNotification Random Like unrecognized exception

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to use NSNotification to communicate between two swift class. I don't know what am I doing wrong but where other notifications work fine, one of them keeps giving unrecognized selector sent to instance exception randomly. By randomly I mean that each time I execute that code exception is same but class reference is different like __CALayer, __NSArray, __NSSet etc. where I even do not use those classes directly. Any help?

Here is observer class init method:

```
override init() {
        super.init()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "downloadChapter:", name: "downloadListNotification", object: DisplayMangaViewController.self)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "downloadChapter:", name: "downloadListNotification", object: DownloadRequestListViewController.self)
    }
```

and the one I post notification inside :

```
let userInfo = ["downloadList" : self.selectedChapters , "mangaName" : self.obtainedMangaName]
        let notification = NSNotification(name: "downloadListNotification", object: DownloadRequestListViewController.self, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
```

Here is one example exception:

> 2015-09-05 19:49:45.598 TurkİşManga[12708:58814] -[__NSArrayM
>   downloadChapter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fbf9c80dd90 2015-09-05 19:49:45.600 TurkİşManga[12708:58814] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM downloadChapter:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbf9c80dd90'

And also here is the draft of downloadChapter method :

```
func downloadChapter(notification : NSNotification){}
```

Comment: You need to post the error you are seeing, please. Also the first line or two of your "downloadChapter:" func.

Comment: I've edit it Can you please check?

Comment: In my test project I cannot get your error. I would look at the contents of userInfo. Test by setting that to known values like:         let userInfo = ["downloadList" : ["1","2","3"] , "mangaName" : ["a","b"]]  and then see if you can track it down that way.

Comment: By the way observer class directly inherited from NSObject whilst sender class inherited from uiviewcontroller. However this does not matter, does it?

Comment: Are you sure that the observer class is still alive (hasn't been deallocated) when it gets the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my observer class gets deallocated and thus when notification posted there would any observer. So before posting any notification, creating an instance from observer class has solved the problem. Thanks.